# Find the option for pd.head() in colab

Tags: python, pandas

I am doing colab, and I found something weird see this:
pd.head()
[image: head]

But I want to do like this:
[image]

Any solution for this problem?
Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unless you are printing a dataframe using `print` google colab automatically displays the data in table format. If in some cases it doesn't you can force it to show using [`display`](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/generated/IPython.display.html)

You can use `display` form ipython to print mutiple tables.

```
from IPython.display import HTML, display
display(df1)
display(df2)
```

[image]

You can also use `google.colab.data_table` extension to show a table with more functionality.

```
%load_ext google.colab.data_table
from IPython.display import HTML, display
display(df1)
display(df2)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Add:

At the first time %load_ext google.colab.data_table doesn't work.

So do `%load_ext google.colab.data_table` first,

And fo `%unload_ext google.colab.data_table`

then do `pd.head()` will works well !